# Reset post grub splash screen with default

Tags: grub2, 14.04, plymouth

I installed ubuntu-gnome but was not a least bit impressed so decided to revert back to Unity. However post grub (after selecting Ubuntu) there is a gnome splash screen. How to I revert back to the original purple Ubuntu... splash screen? I am using 14.04